# Unity collision with ground doesnt work (noob)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

So I just started working with unity and wanted that my player can only jump when he's touching the ground. I gave a "Ground" tag to my ground and checked, If the player is touching the gameObject with the "Ground" tag, so the grounded bool would be set to true. Somehow my collision doesnt work.

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float speed = 10;
    private Rigidbody2D body;
    private Animator animate;
    private bool grounded;

    private void Awake()
    {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animate = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalInput * speed, body.velocity.y);

        if (horizontalInput > 0.01f)
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(7, 7, 7);

        else if (horizontalInput < -0.01f)
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-7, 7, 7);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && grounded == true)
            Jump();
              
            animate.SetBool("Run", horizontalInput != 0);
            animate.SetBool("grounded", grounded);
       

    }

    private void Jump()
    {
      body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, speed);
        animate.SetTrigger("Jump");
        grounded = false;
    }

    private void OncollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("Collision detected");
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        grounded = true;
        Debug.Log("ground is being touched");
    }
    

}
```

I thought it would be a good idea to let certain steps of this process output a log message, but my log stayed empty after testing.

Comment: Where is OncollisionEnter2D referenced?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: OncollisionEnter2D should have a capital C for collision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`OnCollisionEnter2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) would be the right spelling of what you intented to write. So, change `OncollisionEnter2D` to `OnCollisionEnter2D`, because capitalization matters.

As we're already here and it won't harm, I'd also suggest you to use `CompareTag` instead of `tag == string` as it performs slightly better due to less memory allocation (as you can read here: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/fixing-performance-problems#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b595), so it's a good habit to get used to `CompareTag`:

```cs
if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("MyTag"))
```

To finish up this answer, I'd like to point out that you might want to consider fixing your auto-completion suggestions (in Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code: IntelliSense) in case it doesn't work. With the help of this tool, you'll never misspell something like this again, because the correct name will be suggested as soon as you start writing.

Answer (score 0):

Different from what you wanted, this solution lacks responsiveness, you cant jump repeatedly. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LEUhxe9vUOM )in this video dude uses Boxcast. With this way, boxcast method creates box around the collision box, but one argument of it y offset, before collision box touches the ground, this box touches the ground thus you can jump repeadetly.